# Add Reference Lines to SAS Heatmap

Tags: templates, graph, sas, heatmap, sas-gtl

I am making heatmaps through SAS.  I would like to add reference reference lines (a horizontal and vertical) to the heatmap that split it up into quadrants.  My code right now looks like this:

```
proc template;
  define statgraph heatmapparm;
    begingraph;
      layout overlay;
         heatmapparm x=X_Value y=Y_Value colorresponse=percent / colormodel=(blue yellow red)
          name="heatmapparm" xbinaxis=false ybinaxis=false datatransparency=0;
        continuouslegend "heatmapparm" / location=outside valign=bottom;
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

proc sgrender data=Data template=heatmapparm;
run;
```

This graphs a heatmap of the X and Y variables, but I would like add cross lines to mark the middle of my graph.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `drawline` statement.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatgraph/65377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n19cwbtkb5cslcn1bk80pgw2wxex.htm

This adds lines to the heatmap example from the doc:

```
proc template;
  define statgraph heatmapparm;
    begingraph;
      layout overlay;
        heatmapparm x=height y=weight colorresponse=count /
          name="heatmapparm" xbinaxis=false ybinaxis=false;
        drawline x1=50 y1=0 x2=50 y2=100 /
          x1space=wallpercent y1space=wallpercent
          x2space=wallpercent y2space=wallpercent
          lineattrs=GraphReference  ;
        drawline x1=0 y1=50 x2=100 y2=50 /
          x1space=wallpercent y1space=wallpercent
          x2space=wallpercent y2space=wallpercent
          lineattrs=GraphReference  ;
        continuouslegend "heatmapparm" / location=outside valign=bottom;
      endlayout;
    endgraph;
  end;
run;

proc sgrender data=sashelp.gridded template=heatmapparm;
run;
```

Comment: Excellent!  I had to change from wallpercent to datavalue (so it is using the values from my data), but it otherwise directed me well.  Thank you!